# How to make certain pages https and others http

Tags: php, http, facebook-graph-api, https

I'm experimenting trying to build a web app for an idea that I had. I wanted to basically have people log in over Facebook (so I won't be handling passwords anyway), and add in their student email address (ie .edu). Then, this information would be stored in my site's database.

I realized that since this is potentially sensitive information, it might be a good idea to encrypt--and I wanted to figure out how to use SSL anyway. I installed the certificate and used .htaccess to redirect visitors to the https site... Then I noticed that the jQuery EtherPad plugin I was using had stopped working. Presumably, I will eventually figure out a better fix for using EtherPad, but I was wondering anyway, if there's any purpose to using SSL on the entire site or if it is correct. I had heard that it makes a lot of sense to use https only when users are entering secure information, ie login.

Additionally, I can't quite figure out how to do this. If you enter my site's name, it redirects the homepage to https. Furthermore, from there, any links remain https. However, if you enter a folder ie /about, it will use http until the user goes to the homepage.

Any advice? I hope this is specific enough. I read several other pages, but they were too dense for me and didn't seem to address my specific question. I am a web development and stackoverflow noob.

Below is my .htaccess file. I have a vague understanding of what it means, but not exactly.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/login/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Everything HTTPS all the time. If you have a certificate there's no good reason to do anything else.

Comment: @Sammitch I had a feeling that was more correct. I'm not too concerned about performance. Will I just have to find a better way to use EtherPad? (note, I was hoping to install and host it on my server, but I am not experienced enough with node.js)

Comment: @Sammitch Also, what should my .htaccess file be? I'd like to rewrite the urls using https and www